# Ember.js checkbox binding initial value set incorrectly

Tags: javascript, checkbox, ember.js

Somehow the checkbox in my Ember app is always initially checked.

```
...
{{#each model.fields}}
...
  {{input type="checkbox" checked=isOptional}}
```

The fields array is an attribute in my model. Each object in fields array has an attribute called isOptional, which can be "true" or "false".

For some reason, regardless of the value of isOptional, the checkbox is initially checked.

If I check the checkbox manually, the isOptional flag will actually be changed. So the binding works except for detecting the initial value.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

---

Edit: As discussed in comments, the problem was because my model was returned by `Ember.$.getJSON()`, which has "false" in quotes and was interpreted as true value, resulting in checked checkboxes. I resolved this by over-writing the boolean values:

```
model.fields.forEach(function(field, i) {
  Ember.set(field, 'isOptional', (field.isOptional == 'true'));
});
```

Comment: Are you sure that there isn't ANY value in the isOptional property?  Having ANY value besides false, null, or undefined will result in a checked box.

Comment: Thanks, I think that's likely to be the problem! I use "Ember.$.getJSON" to get my model, which returns "false" in quotes. Is there a simple way to ask Ember to interpret it as boolean?

Comment: I believe this may prove useful - http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.BooleanTransform.html - but TBH I don't use Ember.Data so there may be a better resource than me.

Comment: Thanks. No I'm not using Ember data either, maybe later when it's no longer beta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A jsbin example you can fiddle with
http://emberjs.jsbin.com/kukokiti/1/

If you can provide your own jsbin, we can help out more.

EDIT: You can see the effects of the 'false', in a string value.

The easiest way might be to define a computed property on the model you are using.

Comment: Thanks for helping out.. The isOptional belongs to an element of model.fields array so I think computed property may not help here?

Comment: Updated fiddle to show the how you could do it, if you can stuff the object into a Ember.Object before working with it.

Comment: I see.. using computed property in each element of the array. Well in my case it's easier to go through the array and remove the quotes. But that's a good example and suggestion.